# How to bring the particular record to the last row of the table using custom filter in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs, I need to  use custom  filter to  bring the particular record to  the last row of the table. But,  failing  to  do  it.

Here is the `Html` and the `script` i'm using

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead ng-hide="content == 'true'">
    <tr>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'bucket'">Bucket</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'product'">Product</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'countOfAllocatedAccount'">Allocated # </th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'countOfCollectedAccount'">Collected #</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts'">Pending #</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <thead ng-show="content == 'true'"> 
    <tr>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'bucket'">Bucket</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'product'">Product</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'sumOfAllocatedAccount'">Total Allocated Amount</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'sumOfCollectedAccount'">Total Collected Amount</th>
      <th th-sort by="order" reverse="reverse" order="'sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts'">Total Pending Amount </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-hide="content == 'true'" ng ng-repeat='p in view_data | orderByValue'>
      <td><span>{{p.pseudoBucket}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.product}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.countOfAllocatedAccount}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.countOfCollectedAccount}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts}}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="content == 'true'" ng-repeat='p in view_data'>                          
      <td><span >{{p.pseudoBucket}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.product}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.sumOfAllocatedAccount}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.sumOfCollectedAccount}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{p.sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts}}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the custom filter :

```
CollectApp.filter('orderByValue', function() {
  //$scope.reverse = true;
  alert("Rajini");
  return function(items, field) {
    var filtered = [],
      filteredX = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(p) {
      if (p.pseudoBucket == ">90") {
        filteredX.splice(0, 0, p);
      } else if (p.pseudoBucket.indexOf(">") == -1) {
        filtered.push(p);
      } else {
        filteredX.push(p);
      }
    });
    angular.forEach(filtered, function(p) {
      filteredX.push(p);
    });
    return filteredX;
    //console.log("hi");
  };
});
```

And let me share the image of the output i'm getting now.

[image]
I would like to bring the **">90"** to  the last row. Can  anyone help me?

Comment: Last column you mean last index?

Comment: @ inoabrian I have shared the out put image for the clarification . The first  four records are the value of  ">90"  I need to  show that in the last column .

Comment: Do you mean last row? So the top section is 1-30 and the bottom of the table is >90?

Comment: @JokerDan yeap exactly

Comment: What does filteredX look like when it's returned. I want to see some sample data instead of making my own.

Comment: @ inoabrain you can find the  json here : https://jsonblob.com/64a06c48-d9bd-11e6-90ab-71af966bc2f4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that for some of your data elements you don't have a pseudoBucket value

```js
var data =[{"product":"SBHL","bucket":">90","pseudoBucket":">90","countOfAllocatedAccount":3005,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":3005,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":60549185,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":60549185},{"product":"SBHL+","bucket":">90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":321,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":321,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":23987045,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":23987045},{"product":"SBML","bucket":">90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":732,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":732,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":109971610,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":109971610},{"product":"SBML+","bucket":">90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":31,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":31,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":18662882,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":18662882},{"product":"SBML+","bucket":"1-30","pseudoBucket":"1-30","countOfAllocatedAccount":42,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":42,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":1470250,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":1470250},{"product":"SBML","bucket":"1-30","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":942,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":942,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":11904428,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":11904428},{"product":"SBHL+","bucket":"1-30","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":596,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":596,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":3961615,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":3961615},{"product":"SBHL","bucket":"1-30","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":4810,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":4810,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":14549696,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":14549696},{"product":"SBHL","bucket":"31-60","pseudoBucket":"31-60","countOfAllocatedAccount":1610,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":1610,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":9369038,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":9369038},{"product":"SBHL+","bucket":"31-60","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":182,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":182,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":2353302,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":2353302},{"product":"SBML","bucket":"31-60","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":275,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":275,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":7096213,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":7096213},{"product":"SBML+","bucket":"31-60","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":16,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":16,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":1147017,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":1147017},{"product":"SBML+","bucket":"61-90","pseudoBucket":"61-90","countOfAllocatedAccount":10,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":10,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":1191800,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":1191800},{"product":"SBML","bucket":"61-90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":184,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":184,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":7378650,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":7378650},{"product":"SBHL+","bucket":"61-90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":79,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":79,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":1618234,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":1618234},{"product":"SBHL","bucket":"61-90","pseudoBucket":"","countOfAllocatedAccount":793,"countOfCollectedAccount":0,"countOfPendingCollectionOfAccounts":793,"sumOfAllocatedAccount":6799247,"sumOfCollectedAccount":0,"sumOfPendingAllocatedAndCollectedAmounts":6799247}]


// I think that your problem is that for some of your data elements you don't have a pseudoBucket value
// So it puts the >90 into your normal filtered array.
var fx = [],
    f = [];
data.forEach(el => {
  // Added the el.bucket check here too
  if (el.pseudoBucket == ">90" || el.bucket == ">90") {
    fx.splice(0, 0, el);
  } else if (el.pseudoBucket.indexOf(">") == -1) {
    f.push(el);
  } else {
    fx.push(el);
  }
});

f = f.concat(fx);

// will print out in order >90 being last
f.forEach(el => console.log(el.pseudoBucket));
```

Comment: @inoabrain i'm not able to  see the >90 value in my  html table.